# Restoring MBR and GRUB bootloader

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub

I have accidentally broken my Fedora 19 boot when installing Windows 7. Fedora is a separate HDD drive, but somehow it now has Win bootloader and no GRUB. How can I restore GRUB and fix Linux boot?

I've found this instruction: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html#s2-rescuemode-boot-reinstall-bootloader
So I've made Fedora live USB stick, booted from it and... I don't understand what  "installation boot prompt" is. This live CD boots into regular KDE desktop, and if I launch console and type `linux rescue` it says there's no binary called `linux`.

Advices please?

Comment: GRUB or GRUB2? Use the terminal method from this tutorial http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: @Ramhound: don't know, whatever is default for Fedora nowadays. Will try, thanks.

Comment: The instructions are different.  Figure what version of GRUB you have installed if you want help.

Comment: @Ramhound: how? Actually, I don't care what GRUB version it is as long as it boots my Linux.

Comment: If you try using the instructions for the wrong version you will simply break your installlation beyond repair. You need to research how to determine what version of Grub you have installed then follow the correct procedure to fix it.  I am not going to research how to repair Grub and determine what version you have installed.

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain the downvote?

Comment: The question shows a lack of research on your part.  I had to pull teeth to attempt to get information out of you in order to help you.  Its also not the first question on how to repair Grub.

Comment: @Ramhound: that's all the information I have so far. What can I do if even Fedora wiki is wrong / incomplete? I'm not a Linux expert. In Windows this kind of problem is resolved with a few clicks and 5 minutes time.

Comment: This problem is also saved in that amount of time.  It's well documented link to once said document.. What makes you think the wiki is wrong?

Comment: @Ramhound: Let me quote the wiki. Step 1: _Boot the system from an installation boot medium_ - done. Step 2: _Type `linux rescue` at the installation boot prompt to enter the rescue environment_ - what in the world is installation boot prompt??

Answer (score 0):

The boot prompt can be accessed by pressing ESC on this screen (which is displayed before actual Fedora loading starts when booting from installation DVD):

[image]

I've typed `linux rescue`, followed further instructions from the article linked in my question and everything worked like charm. The only other issue was that Fedora Live CD doesn't have linux rescue mode. Only the DVD does.